# In a UML, can I show the connection of instantiated classes from within the cpp files?

Tags: c++, uml, enterprise-architect

In EA is there a way to show the connection of instantiated classes from within the cpp files?

Otherwise all those relations are for not, and I have to go through the code then?

thx

Comment: Do you mean by reverse engineering the code? Then no, EA uses only the header files and you'll see relations only for class member instantiations.

Comment: So then all the instantiated relationship done in the cpp files are not shown?  So then I have to go through all the code line by line or search for each individual class?  Seems like I am missing something here.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so. Usually I'll draw (call) depencency relationships for these. But this will mainly concern kind of 'helper' classes that are used to do localized specific tasks like formatting, parsing, calculations, etc.

Comment: Are you still struggling with that 3rd party legacy lib? I told you don't expect to get into the API just from the structural class diagrams.

Comment: No, I am implementing some new features to this legacy code based on new similar code.  I was thrown into this project.  I am trying to figure out how to navigate to make these upgrades.

Comment: Oh, then it's even worse, if you need to get comfy with the internals. Do you have any kind of documentation, or just the code? Running a tool like doxygen might help, because it also takes into account to show call dependencies.

Comment: Just code for the most part.  Comments in the code are at a minimal as well.

Comment: And I guess there's nothing like doxygen comments for classes and members. You can try doxygen running in auto documentation mode though and see if you get any usable results. Another way to get references for particular instantiations is to use your IDE (Visual Studio AFAIRC). Select a particular class constructor and let the IDE search for call references, but this can get quite tedious ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15397/discussion-between-g-makulik-and-jdl)